# Dockerfile ENTRYPOINT ignores WORKDIR

Tags: docker, dockerfile

`Dockerfile`:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime-deps:7.0.10-alpine3.18-amd64
ARG APP_DIR=/var/lib/app/
WORKDIR $APP_DIR
# etc.
ENTRYPOINT ["MyApp"]     # executable file located at /var/lib/app/MyApp
```

When running that container:

> docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create task for container: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "MyApp": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown.

I specified `WORKDIR`, so why is the executable not found?

(It works if I use `ENTRYPOINT ["/var/lib/app/MyApp"]`, so it's not a permissions issue.)

Comment: The `WORKDIR` should be honored by the `ENTRYPOINT`. Perhaps something that is omitted and shown as "etc" is changing the `WORKDIR`. Can you create a minimum, reproducible example?

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar Thanks for confirming. I will do that.

Comment: WORKDIR is relevant for container build, not for running it. In your simplified example, do an exercise: -First run pwd to know where you are and then “ls “ to check if  the script.sh file is there.

Comment: @aleph Thanks. Note that the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#workdir) state: *"The WORKDIR instruction sets the working directory for any RUN, CMD, ENTRYPOINT, COPY and ADD instructions that follow it in the Dockerfile"*. So I'm unsure why this fails?

Comment: Check if you are copying somewhere and then moving to somewhere else!

Comment: I would set WORKDIR before copying script.sh, so that it is in the same place as I will try to use it.

Comment: @aleph That shouldn't change the result. Like I showed above, the executable is in the right place, and if I use a full path it works. Just to be sure though, I tried your way: I moved the WORKDIR before COPY, and as expected it didn't change the result.

Comment: This is what would work: ```ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "script.sh"]``` In the docs, it states something about shell processing.

Comment: @SebastianLiebscher Thanks that works. I was asked to change my code to a minimal repro so some context was lost in the edits. In the original code, I had `ENTRYPOINT ["MyApp"]` where that is a binary executable. I would need to use `sh` in that case too?

Comment: I'm reverting to the original code.

Comment: If you can start `MyApp` via shell like `./MyApp`, then yes.

Comment: But [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#exec-form-entrypoint-example) show that for "exec form" of ENTRYPOINT, the shell is implied. I'm confused... :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the PATH does not contain the current directory, then you need to explicitly request a binary in the current directory with a `./`:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["./MyApp"]
```

Comment: So obvious it's embarrassing. Sometimes it's easy to forget that underneath all the docker magic is just plain linux. Thanks Mitch!